# Are $A = \{A\}$ and $B = \{B\}$ sets equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set so that $A = \{ A \}$, and let $B$ be a set so that $B = \{ B \}$.

Ignoring the axiom of foundation, **are the sets A and B equal ?**

Comment: isomorphic perhaps, but there is no reason to consider them equal.  For the same reason that the set $A = \{a\}$ is not considered equal to the set $B = \{b\}$, there is no reason to assume that in your definition that $A$ and $B$ refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

It is perfectly consistent, with the failure of the axiom of foundation, that there are infinitely many (and in fact class many) different sets of the form $x=\{x\}$. Of course it is also consistent that there is exactly one.

Sets of this form, by the way, are called Quine's atoms.